# How can i change the color of the predefined buttons in apple research kit

Tags: ios, colors, researchkit

I am trying to make a survey using Apple's ResearchKit but I couldn't find how to change the color of the predefined buttons. They are blue but I want to make them of a different color. How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Using `UIView`'s appearance proxy to set the tint color should work:

```
[UIView appearance].tintColor = yourColor;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very late now but might save somebody's time, worked for me:

taskviewcontrollerobject.view.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; // color of your choice